# Clean VS22 new project gives error NU1301 The local source '...Devexpress 20.2...' doesn't exist

Tags: .net, visual-studio, devexpress, maui

I installed Visual Studio 2022 latest version and created a MAUI app and voila it doesn't build
there are 60 lines of this same error -

```
The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 20.2\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore' doesn't exist.    MauiApp4    C:\Users\gymbo\source\repos\MauiApp4\MauiApp4.csproj    1
```

And another one saying the AndroidManifest.xml does not exist in the root folder, this one is fixed by moving it from ~\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS2022 community, removed Visual studio code and everything else but still the same error

I can't find where it is picking up the Devexpress 20.2 references from, I had it earlier but haven't had that version for over a year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - seems like nuget package manager config file had references to devexpress so removed it as a source there and it worked

Goto Tools > options > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources

And Remove DevExpress (in this case ) from there